# parsing a string into separate strings

Tags: c, parsing

gcc 4.6.1 c89

I have a string that I need parse. The string is sdp information. I am trying to seperate each of the elements into seperate strings.

Basically the string would contain some thing like this:

```
v=0 o=sip_user IN 10230 22472 IP4 10.10.10.44 s=SIP_CALL c=IN IP4 10.10.10.44 m=audio 49152 RTP/AVP 0 8 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
```

And I would like to seperate them into different strings. So this needs to be broken down into seperate strings.

```
str1 v=0 
str2 o=sip_user IN 10230 22472 IP4 10.10.10.44 
str3 s=SIP_CALL 
str4 c=IN IP4 10.10.10.44 
str5 m=audio 49152 RTP/AVP 0 8 
str6 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 
str7 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
```

I was trying to do something like this as a start. But even though it finds the v= I need to find when the next line will start.

```
char *str_v = NULL  
str_v = strstr(sdp_string, "v=");

if(str_v != NULL) {
    printf("found line: [ %s ]", str_v);
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in C? Sounds like a job for a good scripting language.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that difficult. Just wanted an idea how to get started. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the beginnings of all substrings (`parts` array below), then null terminate each of them. This is just to show how simple it can be to parse if the format is fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
        char input[] = "v=0 o=sip_user IN 10230 22472 IP4 10.10.10.44 s=SIP_CALL c=IN IP4 10.10.10.44 m=audio 49152 RTP/AVP 0 8 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000";
        char *parts[16] = {0};
        int top = 0;
        int i;
        char *s = input;
        while (top < 15 && (s = strchr(s, '='))) {   /* find each = and save a pointer to before it */
                parts[top++] = s-1;
                s++;
        }
        for (i = 1; parts[i]; i++)
                parts[i][-1] = '\0';  /* null terminate each part */
        for (i = 0; parts[i]; i++)
                printf("%s\n", parts[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char source[] ="v=0 o=sip_user IN 10230 22472 IP4 10.10.10.44 s=SIP_CALL c=IN IP4 10.10.10.44 m=audio 49152 RTP/AVP 0 8 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000";
    char *str[7];
    char *pf=source, *ps;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        pf = strchr(pf, '=');
        ps = strchr(pf+1, '=');
        if(ps == NULL)
            ps = source + sizeof(source)/sizeof(char);
        else
            ps -=2;
        pf -= 1;
        str[i]=(char*)malloc((ps - pf + 1)*sizeof(char));
        strncpy(str[i], pf, ps - pf);
        pf+=2;;
    }
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        printf("str%d %s\n", i+1, str[i]);
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        free(str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtok` http://husnusensoy.wordpress.com/2007/01/13/strtok-for-c-guys/

you can use `strtok` to split the spaces and then again in that loop split the `=`'s

Answer (score 1):

[`strtok`](http://ideone.com/LpmtY) is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strchr` to find the `'='`, then search backwards from that point to the first space. Then you know when the next string starts. Use `strndup` (not the 'n' in the function name) to create the strings. Continue until you reach end of original string.

If you use `strndup` or any other function to allocate memory, remember to `free` the memory later.